# Why Emulator renders different result to Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have played around with Android Studio and just wonder why the render result is so different to what i created
[Here is the image of my screen, you can see that the 2 screen of Android Studio and Genymotion are completely different](http://screencast.com/t/MlDyOpT8xiZ)

Here is the XML file for the layout, basically i just drag and adjust the margin, width and height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="tk.miendatmoi.widgetexperiments.WidgetExperimentsActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_widget_experiments"
android:visibility="visible">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Left Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:width="150dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Right"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:width="80dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="65sp"
    android:width="150dp"
    android:height="150dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:alpha=".5"
    android:background="#342a2a"
    android:textColor="#fdfdfd"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:src="@android:mipmap/sym_def_app_icon"
    android:contentDescription="incon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using two different layouts. It seems like the **genymotion layout is using tablet layout which has a different resolution to the one is in android studio which is using the nexus 4 resolution.**

Comment: I actually tried this layout code in both phone and tablet emulators. It is not an issue of screen resolution, as both emulators show the layout in David's link.

Answer (score -1):

The result in the emulator is different from the Android Studio preview because you are displaying your layout inside a widget. The tools in the Android Studio layout preview are unable to display the layout inside a widget, so they instead show you the layout as if it were allowed to take up the entire screen. The layout it is displayed correctly inside the widget when you run the application.